# Convert this perl replacement to python

Tags: python, regex, perl, python-2.7

I am trying to port some perl code over to python. Not being proficient in perl is a challange, but I've got most of it done. There is one function however that performs a word replacement which I don't know if there is a straight-forward python equivelent.

```
$my_string =~ s/^(.*?) \(The\)$/The $1/;
$my_string=~ s/\bL\.? ?L\.? ?C\.?\b//;
$my_string =~ s/[(),]//g;
```

I suppose that I could use something such as:

```
re.sub('s/^(.*?) \(The\)$', '$/The 1/', my_string)
```

for the first sample, but I am clueless as to the others.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the `s/` and `/` parts here, and use `\1` for back references. Using raw strings makes this workable:

```
my_string = re.sub(r'^(.*?) \(The\)$', r'The \1', my_string)
my_string = re.sub(r'\bL\.? ?L\.? ?C\.?\b', '', my_string)
my_string = re.sub(r'[(),]', '', my_string)
```

These replacements are 'global' by default (what the `g` flag does); add a integer count as a 4th argument if you need to limit this:

```
my_string = re.sub(r'^(.*?) \(The\)$', r'The \1', my_string, 1)
my_string = re.sub(r'\bL\.? ?L\.? ?C\.?\b', '', my_string, 1)
my_string = re.sub(r'[(),]', '', my_string)
```

Comment: @Blender: yup, fixed.

Comment: Note Python's `re.sub` is global (the /g) by default. If you want just the first item replaced specify count=1.